# multiple skill selection in a single text field

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.skills = [".Net","abc","account","Ajax","Android","Angular JS","Appium","c","Cobol","commerce"];
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" style="margin-left:100px;color:#000;" name="skills" id="skills" class="form-control" ng-required="true" placeholder="Core Skills"  ng-focus="skillsforJobs(model.Skills)" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/" ng-model="model.Skills" typeahead="skills.name for skills in skills | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10" ng-click="resetCity()"required/ >
```

Question:when selecting the skill from the the text field should able to select multiple skills simultaneously and should append comma?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngTagsInput.

https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput

Check out http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos for the demo